# how to read data from a json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json file with this object:

```
{
    "fontFamily": "Roboto",
    "color": "red",
    "backgroundColor": "green",
    "textForExample": "Hello world i'm a text that's used to display an exemple for my creator."
}
```

and when i'm parsing it I have an error in my console that says "infosFile.json:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"
and then when I'm trying to use it in my Javascript, I got this message in console: "infosFile is not defined", I don't understand where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

The json is valid. You can check if you json file is valid at the following link: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

The problem could be that in order to read json from your computer with JavaScript you need NodeJS installed.
You can download NodeJS from here: https://nodejs.org/en/

You can read json with NodeJS like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('<path/yourFileName>.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: i tried this but i have an error saying 'require is not defined'

Comment: Are you using it on the client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const info = require('infosFile.json');

console.log(JSON.parse(info)) // should output valid data
```

Comment: i tried this but i have an error saying 'require is not defined'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the right path to access your JSON file

use **require("")** to access your json file and put your inside the double quotes

use **JSON.parse()** to read and store it inside a variable

```
const json_file = require("./json/test.json");
const data = JSON.parse(json_file);
```

You could also stringify it by using

```
const data_stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, i don't know why but I still have this message "script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", i'm sad

Comment: and i still have this message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'" for my json file

Comment: @RégisLeRégisseur are you using it in the client side or server side? can you show a code snippet

Comment: @RégisLeRégisseur have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: i use it in the client side

Comment: so the problem here is that require() is not built-in the browser. You have to use tools like browserify which is the main purpose is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser. Have a look at their github and try to install them https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage

Comment: i have checked the first link you sent and they were saying that using webpack will fix my problem with require but now that webpack is installed, my problem isn't fixed, i'm trying to look at the second link

Comment: it doesnt work with browserify, what should i do

Comment: do you have a github repo? Maybe I can check it out

Comment: i don't have a github repo but i think i can create one

Comment: sorry but i dont know why my github account is flagged so you can't access the repo, bad day sad day